# Emit Tuples From Erlang Views In CouchDB

Tags: erlang, couchdb, tuples

CouchDB, version 0.10.0, using native erlang views.

I have a simple document of the form:

```
{
   "_id": "user-1",
   "_rev": "1-9ccf63b66b62d15d75daa211c5a7fb0d",
   "type": "user",
   "identifiers": [
       "ABC",
       "DEF",
       "123"
   ],
   "username": "monkey",
   "name": "Monkey Man"
}
```

And a basic javascript design document:

```
{
   "_id": "_design/user",
   "_rev": "1-94bd8a0dbce5e2efd699d17acea1db0b",
   "language": "javascript",
   "views": {
     "find_by_identifier": {
       "map": "function(doc) {
          if (doc.type == 'user') {
            doc.identifiers.forEach(function(identifier) {
              emit(identifier, {\"username\":doc.username,\"name\":doc.name});
            });
          }
       }"
     }
   }
}
```

which emits:

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"user-1","key":"ABC","value":{"username":"monkey","name":"Monkey Man"}},
{"id":"user-1","key":"DEF","value":{"username":"monkey","name":"Monkey Man"}},
{"id":"user-1","key":"123","value":{"username":"monkey","name":"Monkey Man"}}
]}
```

I'm looking into building an Erlang view that does the same thing.  Best attempt so far is:

```
%% Map Function
fun({Doc}) ->
    case proplists:get_value(<<"type">>, Doc) of
    undefined ->
        ok;
    Type ->
        Identifiers = proplists:get_value(<<"identifiers">>, Doc),
        ID = proplists:get_value(<<"_id">>, Doc),
        Username = proplists:get_value(<<"username">>, Doc),
        Name = proplists:get_value(<<"name">>, Doc),
        lists:foreach(fun(Identifier) -> Emit(Identifier, [ID, Username, Name]) end, Identifiers);
    _ ->
        ok
    end
end.
```

which emits:

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"user-1","key":"ABC","value":["monkey","Monkey Man"]},
{"id":"user-1","key":"DEF","value":["monkey","Monkey Man"]},
{"id":"user-1","key":"123","value":["monkey","Monkey Man"]}
]}
```

The question is - how can I get those values out as tuples, instead of as arrays?  I don't imagine I can (or would want to) use records, but using atoms in a tuple doesn't seem to work.

```
lists:foreach(fun(Identifier) -> Emit(Identifier, {id, ID, username, Username, name, Name}) end, Identifiers);
```

Fails with the following error:

```
{"error":"json_encode","reason":"{bad_term,{<<\"user-1\">>,<<\"monkey\">>,<<\"Monkey Man\">>}}"}
```

Thoughts?  I know that Erlang sucks for this specific kind of thing (named access) and that I can do it by convention (id at first position, username next, real name last), but that makes the client side code pretty ugly.

Comment: I don't know the CouchDB details, so I have no idea what function `Emit` refers to, but apparently json_encode used in CouchDB requires a list as input. See:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/couchdb/trunk/src/couchdb/couch_util.erl?view=markup#l317

Comment: Emit is the function that returns data from the map function to be reduced later on.  It has an equivalent in the JS version, and I presume they're both built into the CouchDB view mechanism.

Thanks for the link.  That explains why it doesn't work.  Now, to find out how to work around it :)

Comment: I know what emit is in general; I just don't know the function referred by the `Emit` variable in your pasted code.

Comment: Could you please also indicate how to do this using positions ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The JSON object `{"foo":"bar","baz":1}` is `{[{<<"foo">>,<<"bar">>},{<<"baz">>,1}]}`

In Erlang lingua it is a proplist wrapped in a tuple.

It's not pretty, but very efficient :)

To get a feel for it you can play with the JSON lib that ships with CouchDB:

1. Start CouchDB with the -i
   (interactive) flag
2. On the resulting erlang shell, type: `couch_util:json_decode(<<"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}">>).`
3. Profit

// in later versions of CouchDB, this is `ejson:decode()`

Comment: Perfect!  This really helped :)

Comment: When decoding json which has nested keys, does one need to escape the { with a \{ as well ?

Answer (score 3):

For *test_suite_reports* bd, that has *tests* field:

```
[
   {
       "name": "basics",
       "status": "success",
       "duration": 21795
   },
   {
       "name": "all_docs",
       "status": "success",
       "duration": 385
   } ...
```

I have wrote this to get name and status:

```
fun({Doc}) ->
  Name = fun(L) ->  proplists:get_value(<<"name">>, L, null) end,
  Status = fun(L) -> proplists:get_value(<<"status">>, L, null) end,
  Tests = proplists:get_value(<<"tests">>, Doc, null),
  lists:foreach(fun({L}) -> Emit(Name(L), Status(L)) end, Tests)
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like *experimental features* (that still work...), you might want to have a look to Erlang [exprecs](http://forum.trapexit.org/viewtopic.php?p=21790).

I found it extremely helpful in creating a sort of *dynamic records* for Erlang.