# How does CouchDB calculate the Revision number

Tags: erlang, couchdb

I'm trying to understand how CouchDB calculates the revision id for a document.  I notice from the source that it's calculated by this bit of code here:

```
couch_util:md5(term_to_binary([Deleted, OldStart, OldRev, Body, Atts2]))
```

And I know that if I create a new empty document with no attachments, CouchDB always gives it a revision of 1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d which, in decimal is <<150,122,0,223,245,224,42,221,65,129,145,56,171,179,40,77>>.

However, if I type the following into the erlang prompt  (false for deleted, 0 for OldStart, 0 for OldRev, an empty body and no attachments):

```
erlang:md5(term_to_binary([false, 0, 0, [], []])).
```

I always get

```
<<26,196,244,40,211,149,193,185,214,6,230,61,54,138,62,132>>
```

back.

So what am I doing wrong here - how can I work out the actual revision that couch generates?

Comment: Why do you need to preemptively determine the _rev number? You get the generated number in the response from the server after any write.

Comment: It's because I'm interested in making a different data store sync with couchdb, and for proper syncing both sides should compute the revision id in the same way.

Comment: so have you figured out, how its done? have you a documentation for it ? I have no idea bout erlang, I am trying to re-create a replicator in dart langauge, so any help on it will be helpful ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading the answer to [Emit Tuples From Erlang Views In CouchDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414811/emit-tuples-from-erlang-views-in-couchdb) I realised that what I was doing wrong was not wrapping the empty proplist for body in a tuple.  I'm not sure why couch does that, but that's what the problem was.

```
erlang:md5(term_to_binary([false, 0, 0, {[]}, []])).
```

Gives the correct answer

<<150,122,0,223,245,224,42,221,65,129,145,56,171,179,40,77>>

Comment: A 1-tuple containing a list almost always indicates a JSON-type (key/value) data structure, either just out-of or about to go in-to the JSON serializer. `{[{<<"like">>, <<"this">>}, {<<"cool">>, true}]}` would be `{"like":"this", "cool":true}`. Without the 1-tuple, it would look like just any other Erlang list (or string).

Comment: For updating the database, the next _rev with be
`erlang:md5(term_to_binary([false, 1, <<150,122,0,223,245,224,42,221,65,129,145,56,171,179,40,77>>, {[]}, []])).`
which is 
<<112,81,203,229,200,250,236,208,133,163,250,97,158,110,99,55>>