# How does CouchDB calculate the Sequence Id (seq)

Tags: couchdb

I am looking for pseudo code or the actual code in the source repository (https://github.com/apache/couchdb) defining how CouchDB calculates the `seq` value.

Reviewing the technical overview in the docs: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/intro/overview.html it says:

> Each update to a database instance generates a new sequential number.

But it doesn't go into how. I think that it may be implementation dependent, looking at the replication protocol docs it states:

> **Sequence ID:**
>   An ID provided by the Changes Feed. It MUST be incremental, but MAY NOT always be an integer.

```
 1-g1AAAAIreJyVkEsKwjAURZ-toI5cgq5A0sQ0OrI70XyppcaRY92J7kR3ojupaSPUUgotgRd4yTlwbw4A0zRUMLdnpaMkwmyF3Ily9xBwEIuiKLI05KOTW0wkV4rruP29UyGWbordzwKVxWBNOGMKZhertDlarbr5pOT3DV4gudUC9-MPJX9tpEAYx4TQASns2E24ucuJ7rXJSL1BbEgf3vTwpmedCZkYa7Pulck7Xt7x_usFU2aIHOD4eEfVTVA5KMGUkqhNZV-8_o5i
```

This questions is somewhat related in that it's asking how it calculates another component of a document, the rev:

[How does CouchDB calculate the Revision number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5954864/1060314)

Comment: There is no inherent meaning in the sequence number, other than that it always increments. In practice this means the only predictable part is the integer before the first '-' character. The rest is, indeed, implementation specific, and effectively random. Maybe if you can describe the problem you're trying to solve a more useful answer can be provided.

Comment: Oh I understand there's inherent meaning. I'm literally curious in the implementation used to generate that value (not the leading integer). I have no actual problem I am trying solve with it or no CouchDB use for it, literally just curiosity. I don't read Erlang well, so it's slow-going browsing though the source. I'm sure it wasn't randomly decided to just use this format in 2.x where the 1.x format was different. I just like knowing how folks arrive at their choices seeing how the sausage is made so-to-speak.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't know the answer. It looks like it's at least (partially) base64-encoded--probably including a timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find [here](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/fb5be24cfc9df28c788ab28973bc09828f2d0c4380d8594921cdf619@%3Cuser.couchdb.apache.org%3E) some information about the change sequence internals

The sequence number reflects the cluster state for a document update sequence, this information is encoded into the sequence number.

The numeric part of the sequence number is the sum of the update sequences of a document in each of the cluster nodes.

The second part of the sequence number is a base64 encoded string with the update sequence information in each of the cluster nodes.