# Couchdb watch changes feed in clustered mode returning random changes for the same since value

Tags: couchdb

According to the internet.  You make a request to `/_changes?since=0&limit=1` do what you want with the change, then use the `last_seq` value and pass to `since` and request again.

My problem is, this skips changes.  You can keep requesting `/_changes?since=0&limit=1` and get a different change over and over.  Only occasionally actually getting the first change to the database.  Sometimes you get the 7th change, or the 4th, etc.  If you then repeat but using the `last_seq` value, it skips ahead further, far as I can tell, it never goes back and gets the changes it skipped.

Is there a proper way to periodically watch a couchdb changes feed without using the sockets method instead when using clusters?

What we have right now is a php script that runs on a cron task and requests the last 1000 changes, then it works through them and syncs up SQL databases to match what was in couchdb.  With couchdb skipping changes, this is a big problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CouchDB 2.x doc states that ([see](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.3.1/api/database/changes.html)):

> "The results returned by **_changes** are partially ordered. In other words, the order is not guaranteed to be preserved for multiple calls."

So, when you call /_changes?since=0&limit=1 you obtain a different result as the order is not guaranteed.

The _changes response contains a pending attribute with the number of elements that are out of the response. If you take the last_seq value from the last request and use that value as the since attribute in the next request you'll get the next bunch of changes and the pending value is decreased consistently.

Also, you should be careful with the next documentation note:

> If the specified replicas of the shards in any given **since** value are unavailable, alternative replicas are selected, and the last known checkpoint between them is used. If this happens, you might see changes again that you have previously seen. Therefore, an application making use of the _changes feed should be ‘idempotent’, that is, able to receive the same data multiple times, safely.

Read changes in batches is a recommendation of the CouchDB Replication Protocol ([see](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/replication/protocol.html#read-batch-of-changes)) used by CouchDB compatible clients as Cloudant Sync, so the approach you described should be correct.

Please, don't use the numeric value of the change seq as a reference to infer that there are missed changes as this number is computed from cluster state which may vary between calls. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962975/how-does-couchdb-calculate-the-sequence-id-seq) for more detail.