# emitting value of nested hash in erlang view

Tags: erlang, couchdb

i try to emit the `postal_country` in my view and i have no idea how this would be done in erlang.

this is the structure of my document:

```
{
   ...
   "postal_address": {
       "postal_country": "BE"
       ...
   }
}
```

this is the js i want to translate:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc['ruby_class'] == 'Company' && doc['postal_address']['postal_country']) {
    emit(doc['postal_address']['postal_country'], 1)
  }
}
```

this is what i tried in erlang:

```
fun({Doc}) ->
  case proplists:get_value(<<"ruby_class">>, Doc) of
    <<"Company">> ->
      Addr = proplists:get_value(<<"postal_address">>, Doc, null), 
      Key = proplists:get_value(<<"postal_country">>, Addr, null),
      Emit(Key, 1);
    _ ->
    ok
  end
end.
```

Comment: Do you get an error with this function? Emit seems to be an unbound variable...

Comment: _(FYI @Isac Emit is a function from CouchDB: he's writing a CouchDB map function)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unwrap Address as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2422631/453605:

```
fun({Doc}) ->
  case proplists:get_value(<<"ruby_class">>, Doc) of
    <<"Company">> ->
      case proplists:get_value(<<"postal_address">>, Doc) of
        {Address} ->
          Country = proplists:get_value(<<"postal_country">>, Address),
          Emit(Country, 1);
        _ ->
          ok
      end;
    _ ->
      ok
  end
end.
```

Comment: looks promising. right now the view generation crashes with `** Reason for termination == 
** {{badmatch,null},[{erl_eval,expr,3,[]}]}` at least i think this is the relevant error. do i need to check for null somehow? the erlang stack ist not really helpfull to me...

Comment: I've update the sample to account for `doc['postal_address'] == null`.