# CouchDB performance issue reducing pair of values

Tags: performance, mapreduce, couchdb

Using CouchDB, I'm getting very poor performance trying to compute a "last pass" and "last fail" time over a set of automated test results.

I have a DB of ~5000 records of the form:

```
{
   "completionTime": "2013-06-06T17:28:09.384Z",
   "environment": "ENV1",
   "passed": true,
   "duration": 59142,
   "summary": "",
   "origin": {
       "rowId": "1",
       "worksheet": "Sheet1",
       "workbook": "book.xlsm"
   }
}
```

I have a view defined with map:

```
function(run) {
  if (run.environment && run.origin && run.origin.rowId && run.origin.worksheet && run.origin.workbook && run.completionTime) {
    var key = [run.environment, run.origin.rowId, run.origin.worksheet, run.origin.workbook]
    var completionTime = Date.parse(run.completionTime)
    if (run.passed)
      emit(key, [completionTime, null] );
    else
      emit(key, [null, completionTime] );
  }
}
```

And reduce:

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {
    var latestPass = null;
    var latestFail = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        latestPass = Math.max(values[i][0], latestPass);
        latestFail = Math.max(values[i][1], latestFail);
    }
    return [latestPass, latestFail];
}
```

When querying this view for all results (about 750), it takes anywhere from 10-50 seconds, which is significantly slower than I'd expect.

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to MongoDB, and the same queries ran in hundreds of milliseconds, rather than tens of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

From my limited experience with CouchDB view tuning, I found that writing the view in Erlang significantly improved performance.

Start with this: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/EnableErlangViews

Then write your view in Erlang (some examples): [Emit Tuples From Erlang Views In CouchDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414811/emit-tuples-from-erlang-views-in-couchdb)

It's a bit tricky to get the syntax of the Erlang views correct, but it's fun to try and I saw a little over a 50% increase in performance compared to Javascript views.

Comment: Thanks (and I'd upvote if I had the rep), although I didn't try this -- I really needed a 100x speed increase for my queries.